# Scrapy - selecting with custom attribute value

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to scrap some data not with CSS class but with custom atrribute value.

```
<div data-testid="total-count">We found 45 offers</div>
```

So I need something like that:

```
response.css('div.total-count::text').get()
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you use [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp).

For example:

```
response.css('div[data-testid="total-count"]::text').get()
```